# Why does this execute and summon command throw an error?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to summon a lightning bolt when a repeating command block detects an arrow on grass, but every time the command block runs it throws the error:

> Failed to execute 'summon' on Arrow.

I'm on Minecraft Bedrock version 1.12.1.

Command:

```
/execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass 1 summon lightning_bolt
```

Comment: This needs more details, for example: What Minecraft version are you using? That `/execute` syntax was changed almost two years ago. And what have you tried yourself to solve the problem?

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Comment: Guys, he gave enough information to solve the problem;  The syntax of commands is very different in Bedrock than it is in Java, and it has not changed with the times. He is very simply asking why his command is not summoning a lightning_bolt at an arrow inside of grass and is instead throwing an error. The only reason his command does not work is simply because he is testing for grass with a metadata of 1 instead of a metadata of -1, which means ignore metadata. I believe this question was incorrectly flagged as unclear.

Comment: @ZachK If you know why his command isn't working, you should make a proper answer instead of partially answer in comments.

Comment: I was unable to previously because the post was on hold. I will create a full answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your command is executing at all arrows which are on a block of grass with a metadata of 1; typical grass blocks don't have a metadata of 1. In order to fix this, set the value of 1 to -1, resulting in:

```
/execute @e[type=arrow] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~ grass -1 summon lightning_bolt
```

The value of -1 tells Minecraft to ignore metadata instead of check for it.